# UITextField Crazyness

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

so here's the abridged code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        currentLocation = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        currentLocation.delegate = self;
    ........
    }

    -(void) setState:(NSString *)state andCity: (NSString *)city {

        //currentLocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",state,city];
        currentLocation.text = @"what the shnizzle?";

        NSLog(@"state = %@, and city = %@",state,city);
        NSLog(@"currentLocation.text = %@",currentLocation.text);
}
```

and here's the console output:

```
2009-10-03 16:00:06.311 iParkNow![1061:207] state = (null), and city = New York
2009-10-03 16:00:06.315 iParkNow![1061:207] currentLocation.text = (null)
```

anybody have any idea how this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like currentLocation is nil.  Have you verified that it's getting set properly?